# Writing browser plugin in QT

Tags: c++, qt, documentation, browser-plugin

I would like to try writing a browser plugin in QT.

What browsers will it support?

I couldn't find an updated documenatation (for QT 4.7.0) how to do it.

Can someone provide a link to documentation\tutorial\example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt has no native support for browser plugins. There is a set called Qt Solutions,  [here is git repo for it](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions) , you need qtbrowserplugin solution. it has some docs provided with it, which says it supports

> FireFox, Safari, Opera, Google Chrome, QtWebKit and any other web browser that supports the "Netscape Plugin API"